# Wildcard Certificate with DNS-Suffix

Tags: dns, ssl, certificate

I have an internal domain that is (/ can be) suffixed. For instance:

server1.mynetwork.ken also resolves with server1

I have a self-signed wildcard certificate for mynetwork.ken. When I got to https://server1.mynetwork.ken the certificate is fine but when I go to https://server1 the browser complains about invalid common name (which makes sense).

**What's the easiest way to get around this?**

**Should I create a global wildcard * . * ?**

Comment: I feel this should have been handled by browsers. Because of the DNS suffix the browser perhaps already knows that https://server1/ actually refers to https://server1.mynetwork.ken. Dont know why they dont do it

Answer (score 2):

> What's the easiest way to get around this?

The certificates subject must match the domain name you use. You might try with including just `server1` in the certificate but the best way is to actually use the full name to access the site.

> Should I create a global wildcard * . * ?

Only the leftmost label can include a wildcard. This means `*.*` will not work.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I create a global wildcard * . * ?

I don't think any application will let you do this.

You can achieve this by having an A record of www.server1.mynetwork.ken and then a CNAME record of server1 to www.server1.mynetwork.ken.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way around this is to

Configure your web server to forward http[s]://server1 to https://server1.mynetwork.ken

This means that people (you) type `server1\` in your browser address bar and you automatically arrive at the https version of the full site.

If this is not possible then you would build a certificate specifying, well, anything for the common name, and then use the extension field "alternate names" which is an array, to add as many aliases as you want. Typically:

```
localhost, *.mynetwork.ken, mynetwork.ken
```

If someone goes directly to `https://server1` then there is nothing you can do short of getting an explicit certificate for `server1`. The easiest way is to rely on http to catch the 'convenience' url case, and forward to a fully qualified https.